# functional programming (specifically SML) list interval question

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I have a problem where given two lists representing schedules (periods when someone is busy), I want to return the available times for when both people/lists are available. 
For example,

```
create_schedule([(1,2), (4,6), (8, 12)], [(1,3), (5,9)]] => [(0, 1), (3,4)]
```

All times start from 0 and go up to the max number given in the input. 
This is my approach:

1. Use the List.concat function in order to flatten the list. So, the input becomes `[(1,2), (4,6), (8, 12), (1,3), (5,9)]`.
2. Sort by the first item in each tuple => `[(1,2), (1,3), (4, 6), (5,9), (8,12)].`
3. Merge the intervals so it becomes `[(1,3), (4, 12)].`
4. Take the numbers in between each tuple. For this particular example, I need to insert a (0,0) tuple in the beginning. So for [(0,0), (1,3), (4,12)], the middle values are (0, 1) and (3,4) and that's the answer.

I can't use recursion and my solution has to be in O(nlogn). I've already coded the merge and sort function. Now, I need to create a function that takes the middle values so `[(0,0), (1,3), (4,12)]` becomes `[(0, 1), (3,4)]` (the answer). I'm not sure how to do this without recursion. I'm supposed to use higher-order functions like map, foldl, foldr, filter, etc.. I feel like I have a good start so far but I'm having a lot of trouble finishing it. Any tips would be super helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to create a function that takes the middle values so `[(0,0), (1,3), (4,12)]` becomes `[(0, 1), (3,4)]` (the answer).

One approach: starting with `[(0,0), (1,3), (4,12)]`, you can use `List.tl` and `ListPair.zip` to get `[((0,0),(1,3)), ((1,3),(4,12))]`. Then you just need a function that takes `((0,0),(1,3))` to `(0,1)` and `((1,3),(4,12))` to `(3,4)`.

Another approach: rather than inserting `(0,0)` at the start of the list, you can use `(0, nil)` as the `init` value in a call to `List.foldl`. The `f` will have type `(int * int) * (int * int list)`, and will take `((1,3),(0,nil))` to `(3,[(0,1)])` and `((4,12),(3,[(0,1)]))` to `(12,[(3,4),(0,1)])`. You'll end up with `(12,[(3,4),(0,1)])`, whence you can easily obtain `[(0,1),(3,4)]`.

Comment: The second one was exactly what I was thinking of and I was almost there! Thanks for the help!